LoRa Module OTAA Not Receiving Downlink
We are using the Feather M0 US Region 900 LoRa module to send data to a RAK7258 Gateway. We are able to receive an uplink on the TTN server, but are not receiving a downlink on the module:
000000532701: doWork job started
000000532717: Preparing to send payload
Payload value: 2
000000532745: Packet queued
000000532777: Event: EV_TXSTART
000000869486: Event: EV_TXCOMPLETE
Up: 1, Down: 1
Downlink received
RSSI: -11 dBm, SNR: 7.2 dB
Port: 0
000000900126: Event: EV_TXSTART
000001281895: Event: EV_TXCOMPLETE
Up: 2, Down: 1

000004282702: doWork job started
000004282713: Preparing to send payload
Payload value: 2
000004282746: Packet queued
000004282777: Event: EV_TXSTART
000004664222: Event: EV_TXCOMPLETE
Up: 3, Down: 1

The settings on the uplink message is:
"settings": {
"data_rate": {
"lora": {
"bandwidth": 125000,
"spreading_factor": 10,
"coding_rate": "4/5"
}

The RSSI and SNR is also:
"rssi": -17,
"channel_rssi": -17,
"snr": 11.8,

Would appreciate any advice on where to start debugging and what possible issues there may be.

What is the code running on the Feather? What class is the device set to? What class is the device configured as on TTN? Are you taking into account the relevant dwell time and duty cycle? What is the length of the payload?
